# Word for indirect insult

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word to describe an insult that is thrown indirectly?

E.g. "Hey are you **still considered the fat one**? I mean I myself am used to being called that when I'm at parties."

Comment: That's indirect?  Can you give another example, or maybe elaborate on the characteristics you're referring to?

Comment: Insult is pretty much direct here. The whole tone may be called ironical, mocking, derisive. I personally would call it an irony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered:

Jab

Barb

Insinuation

Snide (adjective) – i.e, Snide remark

Malicious subtext (verbose)